# Css difference in iphone and android?

Tags: android, iphone, css, ios

These days im developing a mobile site for my company.after finish my home page i checked it in a iphone & a android phone. All the things are ok in both devices.But there is a little issue with a  tag.i used a padding-top for this element. It's nicely working in the iphone and padding is not working in the android.What can be the issue? and i want to know there are any hacks for iphone and android?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way Android and iPhone handle the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)? I haven't run into this before myself, but I'd try playing with [box-sizing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fbox-sizing%2F&ei=srg6T-H2G8jYiQLAr-GSDA&usg=AFQjCNELmE2dDl7dfy5nlY-on4lPqTEz4g&sig2=3PwtzeWpkfR8IVrlrIK-kg) (keep in mind you'll need to use the proprietary -webkit- prefix).